# unexpected tIVAR while attempting to use modal for user create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am building a modal for user creation (only an admin can create a user.) I am getting an un expected tVAR error. i have been through my code a number of times now and can not seem to track down where I've gone wrong.

the error is (rails server output:)

```
SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')'
@output_buffer.safe_append='              <...
              ^:
```

I created a second "AdminsController" - Listed Below. 
( My goal here is to redirect to the user_show_page on successful save or redirect to the app root_path if not successful (only the show page has been built i will build out the index at a later time. (I have a feeling this may be where im going wrong.)

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new_user
    authorize! :manage, User
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create_user

    @user = User.new(permitted_params.user)
    authorize! :manage, User
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User has been successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'There was a problem creating this user, please try again.' }
    end
  end

end
```

my routes.rb for the custom paths - below

```
  as :user do
    get "admins/new_user" => "admins#new_user", as: :admins_new_user
    post "admins/create_user/:id" => "admins#create_user", as: :admins_create_user
  end
```

my modal form - below:

```
  <!-- Start - Modles -->
    <!-- Start - New User Creation -->
    <%= form_for(@user, :url => admins_create_user_path do |f| %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="userCreate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New System User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Form Fields HERE....
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <%= f.submit "Create User", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <!-- End - New User Creation -->
  <!-- End - Modles -->
```

the modal has been placed on the application.html.erb page -- this could also be the issue? i am not sure where else to place it, however..

and finally, my modal link (found in navbar):

```
<%= link_to "Create New User", "#userCreate", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you require any further info.

Full Back Trace:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-06-28 13:38:54 -0600
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')'
@output_buffer.safe_append='    <!-- End - New User Creation -->
              ^:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:123:in `'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:309:in `module_eval'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:309:in `compile'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:258:in `block (2 levels) in compile!'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:350:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:257:in `block in compile!'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:245:in `synchronize'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:245:in `compile!'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
  responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:in `to_html'
  responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in `respond'
  responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
  responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:205:in `respond_with'
  devise (4.1.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:12:in `new'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:181:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:31:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/digestor.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'

Started POST "/__better_errors/31d37489ea7d85b0/variables" for ::1 at 2016-06-28 13:38:54 -0600
```

Comment: Could you add the backtrace, please?

Comment: most certainly ill update

Comment: Your `form_for(@user, :url => admins_create_user_path` doesn't have a closing bracket.

Comment: nick, add as an answer and ill award best.. silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Don't mind if I do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_for(@user, :url => admins_create_user_path` doesn't have a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => admins_create_user_path do |f| %>
```

Should be:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => admins_create_user_path) do |f| %>
```